# Methods inside InitialiseComponent causes Designer and Runtime Errors

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I would like to separate my `Form::initializeComponent()` method into many methods. Ie, a method to create tab 1, a method to create tab 2 and call those methods inside `Form::initializeComponent()`. I am doing this to make the code more manageable and readable - its much easier to jump to createTab3() and work out whats going on rather than search through hundreds of lines of code just to find tab3's creation.

Example:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    // Default form creation and initialisation code here

    createTab1();
    createTab2();
    createTab3();

    // Show form code here
}
```

**My Problem:** I cannot view my dialog in the designer - I get an error saying `The variable tab1 is either undeclared or was never assigned`. Thats because that code occurs in `createTab1()`. I also cant run my Release build .exe, it crashes. If I place all my code from `createTab1()` (and all other tab methods) inside `initializeComponent()` then the release .exe runs fine. So the crash is caused by the `createTab1()` code not being directly inside `initializeComponent()`.

**Is there a way I can still have the methods `createTab1()` inside `initializeComponent()` and have the designer work and not have my release .exe crash?**

Or do I have to place all my code inside `initializeComponent()`? Maybe theres a way to tell VS2010 that the method `createTab1()` should execute in 'design mode' or something?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you can add code to the InitializeComponent method, it is recommended that you do not as it is regenerated *every time* you change the UI in the designer.

Maybe you can move your code into your form_load method or even after the call to the InitializeComponent if you want to write your own code to create controls, otherwise if you use the designer then leave the code autogenerated code as it is.